# How can I get the distance between two instructions in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm developing a tool which will inject multi faults into the source code using LLVM. I need to inject a fault into the begin instruction and then the instruction after certain instructions. How can I get the distance between two instructions(using instruction count)? Is there any convenient function to achieve that or the only way is to iterate all instructions within this block and the successors of the block?

Comment: Given two instruction iterators, you can probably use `std::distance()` on them.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not I want. What I actually want is the least executed instruction count between two instructions in IR level.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need distance between instructions in a basic block, you need to iterate on each instruction in a Basic Block. for example. see how each instruction is iterated in: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/2c4ca6832fa6b306ee6a7010bfb80a3f2596f824/lib/Analysis/CodeMetrics.cpp#L121

```
  for (const Instruction &I : *BB) {
    // Skip ephemeral values.
    if (EphValues.count(&I))
      continue;

    // Special handling for calls.
    if (isa<CallInst>(I) || isa<InvokeInst>(I)) {
      ImmutableCallSite CS(&I);
...
```

If you want to have a measure of distance between instructions across basic blocks, it is slightly complicated. It would require the use of DFS visit number of each basic block. Using DFS number along with the position of an instruction relative to it's basic block can be used to have some notion of distance.